# how to read files sequentially from a directory in java?

Tags: java, java-io

```
public class File_Reader 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
{
    int count_files=0;
    int count_lines=0; 
    ArrayList<String> list_row = new ArrayList<String>();
    File dir = new File("/home/sumit/Desktop/split_20");//folder is loaded
    if(dir.exists())
    {
        int i=0;
        for (File file : dir.listFiles())
        {                                       
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file); 
            System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            fl=file.getAbsoluteFile();
            while (s.hasNext())
            {
                list_row.add(s.next());//adding all elements 
                count_lines++;
            }   
            String str[];
            str=new String[count_lines];    
            for(int p=0 ; p<count_lines ; p++)
            {
               str[p]=list_row.get(p);

            }
            count_files++;
            s.close();
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("Count files = "+count_files);
}
}
```

My files are sorted like 1.csv,2.csv,3.csv....so on.
so I want my program to read these files as they appear in folder.But program is reading them randomly like 11.csv,8.csv,20.csv...so on.
I have 24 files inside the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers you have to sort your list of files. There are some convenient functions in [Java NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) to read whole files into `List<String>` and walk the file tree.

In my solution I used a `TreeMap` to sort the file paths and read the files while walking the file tree.

Further you can convert a `List<String>` to an array by invoking `List::toArray(T[])`. So you can write:

```
public static String[] readAllFiles(String path) throws IOException {
    Map<Path, List<String>> readFiles = new TreeMap<>();
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Objects.requireNonNull(file);
            readFiles.put(file, Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> read : readFiles.values()) {
        lines.addAll(read);
    }
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}
```

***EDIT***

If your filenames only containing numbers then you can extract the numbers by regex/splitting/etc. the filename.

Then you have to add this to the constructor of the `TreeMap`

```
Map<Path, List<String>> readFiles = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Path>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
        Matcher o1Matcher = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(o1.getFileName().toString());
        Matcher o2Matcher = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(o2.getFileName().toString());
        if (o1Matcher.find() && o2Matcher.find()) {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1Matcher.group()), Integer.parseInt(o2Matcher.group()));
        } else {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
});
```

And use this Pattern as static field in your class

```
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
```

Comment: plz tell me how to getPaths of Files for printing@Flown

Comment: @Sumit Dharma The paths are stored in the map `readFiles`. You only need to go through the `keySet` of the map.

Comment: i tried readFiles.keySet() but still result is not in sequence

Comment: In which way do you want it?

Comment: It is in ascending order!

Comment: @SumitDharma now you can sort your files if they contain only numbers

Comment: plz help ..the files contain format:192.168.3.10,120.2.5.1,10,1500 (srcIP,destIP,pro no. ,frmLength) ....plz tell me how to fetch only srcIP in ArrayList. @Flown

Comment: @SumitDharma Open a new question. This is answered and it hasn't anything to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the Javadoc, you'll see that there is no guarantee on the order in which files are returned by [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles())

You'll need to sort the returned list: See [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

If the default ordering of File does not suit your need, you could define your own Comparator.

Default ordering by [File.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#compareTo(java.io.File)) :

> Compares two abstract pathnames lexicographically. The ordering
>   defined by this method depends upon the underlying system. On UNIX
>   systems, alphabetic case is significant in comparing pathnames; on
>   Microsoft Windows systems it is not.

Comment: Generally most OS have not quarantee of order

Comment: @Pablo, yes indeed, that is why I had used "eventually". I will edit to make it clearer

Comment: what about linux ? @Benoît

Comment: @SumitKumar, I don't understand your point. I wrote that there is no guarantee on the order (ie : what ever the OS). Linux or Windows will both list files in "unknown" order.
The default File.compareTo behavior will be slightly different on Linux or Windows as stated in the copied Javadoc

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly. Just sort the list of files. And then use that sorted list.

```
List<File> sortedDirs = Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles());
Collections.sort(sortedDirs, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
    }
});

for (File file : sortedDirs){
    ...
}
```

**Collections.sort(List)** will not work. Because `File.compareTo()` doesn't guarantee to return same value on all OS. So you will have to provide your own `Comparator` as I shown above. And will have to use **Collections.sort(List, Comparator)** version

Comment: using this solution error appears : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method sort((File f1, File f2) -> {}) is undefined for the type List<File>
 Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Comment: Okay I will edit my code to work in java 1.7. (but I suggest you to have latest jdk version installed)

Comment: again...and asks me to add cast to method Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method sort(new Comparator<File>(){}) is undefined for the type List<File>

Comment: `List::sort` is a default method added in Java 8. You have to use `Collections::sort`

Comment: @SumitKumar I am sorry, I had java 1.8 installed. I didn't noticed that in java 1.7 `List.sort()` was not there.

Comment: still output is : 1.csv,10.csv,11.csv,12.csv,13.csv,14.csv,15.csv,16.csv,17.csv,18.csv
,19.csv,2.csv,20.csv,21.csv,22.csv,23.csv,24.csv,3.csv,4.csv,5.csv,6.csv,7.csv,8.csv,9.csv
Count files = 24

Comment: @SumitKumar in lexicographical order 10 will come after 1, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

you should sort the filenames prior to the `for`, e.g. something along the lines of

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
for(File f : files) {
  filePaths.add(f.getName());
}
Collections.sort(files);

for(String fName : files) {
  File sortedFile = new File(fName);
  // and so on
```